# How do I access the database created in one activity from another activity?

Tags: android, database, android-activity

I have two activities, Activity A and Activity B.
Activity B is creating a database, inserting data to it, editing data and then closing the database.
Activity A is an empty screen and it calls activity B. Activity B finishes its database work and goes back to activity A. Now I want my activity A to access the database created and modified by Activity B.
It might be a very simple solution, please excuse me if it is a silly question.
Any clue will is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shaista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a DBAdapter class to handle all of your database interaction. The database is SQL Lite and is for the whole application. Just access it in B as you did in A.

Comment: okay, I have created a DBAAdapter class and I am doing all the operation in activity B. In activity A I want to check if db does not exist then do not do anything and if it exists then access it . it is like basically just opening a file it is already there and else do not do anything.

Comment: I got the solution it was very simple as you had explained but apart from this I had to make my activity to be a **single task**. this was very important.
 
'DBAapter db = new DBAapter(this);'
'db.open();'
Then in the manifest I had to use 
'android:launchMode="singleTask"'
Bingo!!! the problem is solved.

Comment: Awesome. I should have posted code but did not have my files with me. The search though was probably a better learning experience though. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

To access the data in Activity A, use the onActivityResult() in Activity A in the following way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, ntent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST && resultCode == 10) {
        pos = intent.getIntExtra("doc_id", 1);
        mDbHelper.open();
        /* Write the database accessing code and whatever you want to do on 
           returning back from Activity B here. */
        mDbHelper.close();
    } 
}
```

And also remember that you can use this method with the intent method with calling `startActivityForResult()` with intent
That's it, what you have to do

If there is any confusion then you can ask

EDIT: This code will help in fetching the data

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
AnyDBAdapter mDbHelper = new AnyDBAdapter(this);
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
mDbHelper.open();
        Cursor foemiCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAll();/*fetchAll() is which you need to create in AnyDBAdapter class showing query for fetching the database */
        startManagingCursor(foemiCursor);
/*Now the query will get executed and you need to access just vales from it, here you write code for it*/
foemiCursor.close();
mDbHelper.close();

}
```

Comment: Okay, this looks interesting thanks. Let me try it and will get back to you.

Comment: @Shaista Naaz : I hope this would be helpful for u

Comment: yes sure will do that but I am still trying to solve it. thanks anyways.

Comment: Hi Nikki, 
I still feel that there may be more simpler way. Like the database is created and now I want to check if the database is present in application ( but not in the same activity ) then check the database with the name that is the name of databse and if it exists then open it. I do not know if it possible but if it is then that would be the simplest approach I believe. I might be wrong also. not sure...

Comment: @Shaista Naaz : Do you have used different class for creating database

Comment: @Shaista Naaz : Can I know what actually you want to do

Comment: yes, 
See I have one helper class file. and multiple other activity. One activity is creating a database and modifying it. Now I want to check from other activity if the database is already created. If so then access it. I want to access the same database table from anywhere in the application from different activity.

Comment: @Shaista Naaz : For that first of all I would like to know wheather you have created different class for you database or not

Comment: Yes I have created a separate class called DBAdapter.java and I have successfully created and edited one database table called myDatabase. Now I want to access this same database from another activity. 
let me know if I am clear to you.

Comment: @Shaista Naaz : I have edited my answer for fetching the data from database in activity. Do you need this thing?

Comment: @Shaista Naaz : You can also view this link for daabase retrieval. Its good! The link is: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954

Comment: thanks Nikki. But I have gone though this before only. This guy is not doing what I am looking for actually this article has helped me a lot but not in what I am exactly looking for now. I am trying to share a database between activities. whish is not being done in this article.

Comment: @Shaista Naaz : For sharing database between activities you can use either global variables sharing that data or use putExtra() of intent

Comment: @Shaista Naaz : Does this helped you or not

Answer (score 1):

use content provider...But directly your activity cannot interact with content provider activity interact with content Resolver and than resolver interact with content provider so now you can access data of other activity.

Comment: is it possible that I check if there is a database existing in the application specifically in other activity then just access it, by calling db.open() or something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

You should check this link, http://kagii.squarespace.com/journal/2010/9/10/android-sqlite-locking.html. It contains some good information on how to use databases on android.

Comment: Here in the example the code has one activity and one helper class.
 but I have multiple activity and one helper class and I want to access same database from everywhere. I do not want to create a new one. Only open the database if already created in another activity and access it.